# What is the use of the bell in android?

Tags: android

What is the use for the bell in Android? And where can I read more about it? Here is one example of an app that contains the bell:

[image]

Comment: The bell? It's just an icon..?

Comment: @TheWanderer Yes but what's the meaning for Android?

Comment: What do you mean? It could be used for anything.

Comment: That's not like its a built in thing in android.  Its an icon some app decided to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bell icon is usually used to access notification configuration.

Comment: Can you give an example? Like I know how to create a notification, why would I want the bell thing in my app?

Comment: Let's take facebook as an example - facebook can send notifications for many different actions, such as receiving friend invite, someone accepting your friend request, someone mentions you in their post, a friend posts something on their wall, a friend goes live, etc. Under this menu, facebook would allow me to choose only the actions i'm really interested in. For example I only want to receive notification when someone mentions me or accepts my friend request, but not for any of the other actions, because I consider them to be unnecessary distractions.